# check in dynamo db table if attribute exist and if it does then fail with reason - boto

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-dynamodb, boto, boto3

I have following python code using boto:

```
import boto3

# Get the service resource.
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2')

# Instantiate a table resource object without actually
# creating a DynamoDB table. Note that the attributes of this table
# are lazy-loaded: a request is not made nor are the attribute
# values populated until the attributes
# on the table resource are accessed or its load() method is called.
table = dynamodb.Table('djin-dev-genesis')

def addtodatabase(appname, chef_max, arp_score):

    response = table.get_item(Key={'appname': str(appname)})
    if 'Item' not in response.keys():
        print "partititon key (appname) not found, creating a new item in dynamo db with the key"
        table.put_item(
           Item={
                'appname': appname,
                'chef_max': True,
                'arp_score': '110'
            }
        )
    else:
        print "partition key = "+str(appname)+" found, here is the item dict : "+str(response['Item'])
```

I want in the else scenario to look if (in case key exists), if any of the attributes value already exists and matches . In that case I want to fail with the reasoning else update the attribute.

What would be the code in boto to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a condition expression on the PutItem call like `attribute_not_exists(appname)` to only allow an item to be created if it doesn't already exist. Catch the ConditionalCheckFailedException and get the item with GetItem otherwise.